# OpenGL draws outside window bounds

Tags: c++, opengl

while drawing a GL_LINE_STRIP I noticed the drawing is outside of window bounds, I can't see half of the drawing.

I want to center it within the window and automatically resize it to fit it.
can someone redirect me to how can I achieve that?

this is what I'm seeing:

[image: example]

I want it to be in that size & position:

[image: exmaple2]

This is my code:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    // GUI Stuff
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE);
    glutInitWindowSize(600, 600);

    glutCreateWindow("Graph showing the waveform after hanning window");
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}

void display()
{
    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST); glDisable(GL_BLEND);
    glDisable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH); glLineWidth(2);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(-6, 6, -6, 6, -1, 1);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();


    glColor4f(0.4, 1.0, 0.6, 1);
    glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);
    for (int i = 0; i < N / 2; i++)
    {
        glVertex2f(frequencies[i], mag[i]);
    }
    glEnd();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

Here is my [full code](https://pastebin.pl/view/59c6241c)

Comment: You need to create a [mcve] that includes some example values for `frequencies' and `mag` that are outside of the window. The values for those exceed likely the range you defined in `glOrtho`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the isseu, you need to know the bound of your curve. You have to change the the orthographic projection:

<s>`glOrtho(-6, 6, -6, 6, -1, 1);`</s>

In Orthographic Projection, the view space coordinates are linearly mapped to the clip space coordinates. The viewing volume is defined by 6 distances (left, right, bottom, top, near, far). The values for left, right, bottom, top, near and far define a cuboid (box).

If you want to center the view on the curve, the center of the projection must be the center of the curve. e.g.:

```cpp
glOrtho(min_x-1, max_x+1, min_y-1, min_y+1, -1, 1);
```

(`min_x`, `min_y`) is the bottom left and (`max_x`, `max_y`)  the top right of the bounding rectangle around the curve.

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
```

```cpp
std::vector<float> x_corrds(frequencies, frequencies + N/2);
std::vector<float> y_corrds(mag, mag + N/2); 

float min_x = std::min_element(x_corrds.begin(), x_corrds.end());
float max_x = std::max_element(x_corrds.begin(), x_corrds.end());
float min_y = std::min_element(y_corrds.begin(), y_corrds.end());
float max_y = std::max_element(y_corrds.begin(), y_corrds.end());
```

Comment: @yarinCohen No. Why do you not set the proper orthographic projection? It doesn't matter if you use `glOrtho` or `glScale`. In either case you need to know the minimum and maximum of the curve. I've provided some code that computes the limit values.

Comment: @yarinCohen The title  of your question is "OpenGL draws outside window bounds". To solve it, you need to know the bound of your curve.

Comment: I'll mark that as solved because I believe that's the correct answer, but glScale worked for me so I'll go with that

Comment: @yarinCohen *"... `glScale` worked for me ..."* is no general solution. It all depends on the arguments. `glScale` as well as `glOrtho` scale the vertices.

Comment: when using your solution I get these warnings: "C26451 Arithmetic overflow: Using operator '+' on a 4 byte value and then casting the result to a 8 byte value. Cast the value to the wider type before calling operator '+' to avoid overflow (io.2)"

Comment: @yarinCohen Where do you get the warning? I don't have your complete code, so you have to fix the warning yourself. Anyway that should be an easy task.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232694/discussion-between-yarin-cohen-and-rabbid76).

Comment: I updated the post with the complete code